# How to delete an aws sub account created from aws organization account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have added terraform script to create an organization account.

After creation, when I ran destroy, it is not deleting the account.

Getting this error:

```
An error occurred (ConstraintViolationException) when calling the RemoveAccountFromOrganization operation: The member account must be configured with a valid payment method, such as a credit card.
```

Using the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618094/create-destroy-aws-account-using-terraform) and answer provided in it, I tried adding close_on_deletion flag to the resource, this time terraform destroy is successful but account is just in suspended state and reapply won't work anyway because of this.

[suspended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l18XE.png)

Removing manually again shows ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: Reopen the account again via https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reopen-aws-account/ which will make you add a payment method and then try to remove it from the org.

Comment: The account is created as part of terraform, so that we can use it for automation purpose and delete it at the end of it.
This solution doesn't work for this

Answer (score 0):

When you create an organisation account it uses the organisation for billing. So when you remove from the organisation the account needs all the credentials to operate as an independent account this includes credit card details for payment.

The errors explains the issue so you need to provide those details.

The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_remove-member-account.html) at point 5 describes this.